# Will I still get the "It was all just lying there" achievement if I miss an item I had collected before?

Tags: achievements, the-last-of-us

I'm playing The Last of Us for the third time (now in hard+) aiming to collect everything. To do this, I'm following [this list](http://www.computerandvideogames.com/411602/features/the-last-of-us-complete-collectibles-guide/) to check the things that I didn't find during my two first gameplays, but I commited a silly mistake :S

I'm finishing the Pittsburg chapter and I missed the last artifact, called "Trial Note" that is near the board in the boardroom at the Architect Office (before crossing the bridge) and I entered in the room that Henry closes before the last strike, so I can't go back. In the `hard` playthroght, I catched this document, but now in `hard+` I missed.

What I want to know is since I catched the artifact before, if it will count as a catched document in order to acquire the trophy "It was all just lying there". In the chapter select interface, inside the main menu, the Pittsburg chapter has all the things collected:

- Artifacts found: 17/17
- Firefly pendants found: 3/3
- Training Manuals Found: 4/4
- Comics found: 4/4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The collectibles are cummulative through different gameplays, so, since I already catched the artifact in a previous gameplay, it counted as a catched artifact, and I got the trophy.